# broadcast sound by phone number as radio (voip multi-unidirectional)

Tags: sip, voip

the church of my village is currently offering to hear Sunday morning preaching by telephone by calling a landline number, useful for the elderly and those with technologic difficulties.
They have subscribed to a conference offer: they call by VoIP, bind the sound card and manage incoming calls throughout a conference interface to mute the microphone of those arriving (requiring a qualified person to manage).
They are having some problems with the host at the moment and I was wondering if there was a simpler solution to implement to offer the same service.

I learn many things about linux, so I search for asterisk + Voip offer, but :
the VOIP offers that I find are all "classic" with free and unlimited calls to 495623 countries.. or  expensive business for many useless services, While the only purpose of this number is to be contacted on weekends, for 2/3 hours, by more than 20 people and hearing a stream that may even have a latency of 1 minute!
Do you have any leads?
thanks.

Comment: How about using a VoIP provider? Are you in USA/Canada? There are many companies up there that can offer call conferencing. We did something similar for a school.. Basically, teacher would dial into a number (using VoIP phone), and students would then dial a 10 digit number. The system was automatically muting all the callers. 
Personally, I think it is less headache if you go with a hosted platform (SaaS) rather than trying to set this up yourself.